# How to remove noise from already smoothed graph

Tags: python, cryptocurrency

```
def check_for_double_top_bot(symbol, time_frame):
 ticker_df = download_binance_candles(symbol, time_frame)
 y_filtered = savgol_filter(ticker_df["Close"], 11, 1)

 x = np.linspace(0, len(ticker_df), len(ticker_df)+1)

 data = y_filtered

 min_max = np.diff(np.sign(np.diff(data))).nonzero()[0] + 1  # local min & max
 l_min = (np.diff(np.sign(np.diff(data))) > 0).nonzero()[0] + 1  # local min
 l_max = (np.diff(np.sign(np.diff(data))) < 0).nonzero()[0] + 1  # local max

 print(min_max, l_max, l_min)
 plt.plot(x[l_min], data[l_min], "o", label="min", color='r')  # minima
 plt.plot(x[l_max], data[l_max], "o", label="max", color='b')
 plt.plot(y_filtered, color='black', label='EURUSD')
 plt.show()
```

I have this code at the moment to find turning points on crypto charts however, the line doesn't seem to be completely smoothed as I still get a large amount of noise.

[current smoothed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6f0A.png)

Is there another filter that can be used to smooth it even further to remove the small noise that is affecting the way I'm finding maxima and minima?

The curve cannot be changed too much as it is important that the turning points stay as same as possible. I'm mainly looking for a way to just reduce the amount of "jaggedness" the curve currently is.

[what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FekEP.png)

As you can see there are unnecessary turning points due to the small noise that is left over

UPDATE:

As suggested in the answers below Ive tried this snippet of code out and works perfectly.

```
ticker_df = download_binance_candles(symbol, "5m")
s = np.random.normal(size=200).cumsum()
print(s)

kwargs = dict(distance=5, prominence=2)
imax, propmax = find_peaks(s, **kwargs)
imin, propmin = find_peaks(-s, **kwargs)

plt.plot(s)
plt.scatter(x=imax, y=s[imax], c='b')
plt.scatter(x=imin, y=s[imin], c='r')
print(imax, imin)
plt.show()
```

[giving this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuhLZ.png)

and these maximas and minimas: [ 12  25  54  67  79  90  97 105 124 133 148 177 190] [ 21  28  33  63  72  85  94 100 115 141 151 185]

However, when I use my pandas series it doesn't work out any maximas or minimas. Even when converted to a np.array.

```
ticker_df = download_binance_candles(symbol, "5m")
s = ticker_df["High"].values
print(s)

kwargs = dict(distance=5, prominence=2)
imax, propmax = find_peaks(s, **kwargs)
imin, propmin = find_peaks(-s, **kwargs)

plt.plot(s)
plt.scatter(x=imax, y=s[imax], c='b')
plt.scatter(x=imin, y=s[imin], c='r')
print(imax, imin)
plt.show()
```

[giving this without maxima or minima](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xlYx.png)

[] []

CSVs that are made into dataframes are like this:

```html
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close,21 Day MA,21 Day STD,Upper Band,Lower Band
2021-08-15 10:05:00,0.09595,0.09625,0.09593,0.09621,618373,0.09621
2021-08-15 10:10:00,0.09623,0.09637,0.09601,0.09637,591335,0.09637
2021-08-15 10:15:00,0.09636,0.09649,0.09628,0.09631,330937,0.09631
2021-08-15 10:20:00,0.09634,0.09634,0.09604,0.09617,434572,0.09617
2021-08-15 10:25:00,0.09619,0.09650,0.09611,0.09627,673191,0.09627
2021-08-15 10:30:00,0.09626,0.09664,0.09609,0.09664,665751,0.09664
2021-08-15 10:35:00,0.09664,0.09673,0.09643,0.09663,884939,0.09663
2021-08-15 10:40:00,0.09670,0.09701,0.09662,0.09694,499309,0.09694
2021-08-15 10:45:00,0.09694,0.09706,0.09678,0.09695,992876,0.09695
2021-08-15 10:50:00,0.09697,0.09697,0.09665,0.09680,342539,0.09680
2021-08-15 10:55:00,0.09681,0.09690,0.09661,0.09689,278168,0.09689
2021-08-15 11:00:00,0.09681,0.09700,0.09658,0.09693,1207392,0.09693
2021-08-15 11:05:00,0.09691,0.09734,0.09691,0.09730,1124751,0.09730
2021-08-15 11:10:00,0.09731,0.09744,0.09722,0.09724,995906,0.09724
2021-08-15 11:15:00,0.09725,0.09743,0.09699,0.09702,1298901,0.09702
2021-08-15 11:20:00,0.09705,0.09732,0.09704,0.09722,910978,0.09722
2021-08-15 11:25:00,0.09725,0.09728,0.09701,0.09722,863326,0.09722
2021-08-15 11:30:00,0.09720,0.09751,0.09694,0.09700,1451370,0.09700
2021-08-15 11:35:00,0.09701,0.09709,0.09655,0.09681,997123,0.09681
2021-08-15 11:40:00,0.09684,0.09719,0.09667,0.09670,807811,0.09670
2021-08-15 11:45:00,0.09667,0.09706,0.09657,0.09666,361049,0.09666
2021-08-15 11:50:00,0.09669,0.09688,0.09610,0.09659,1156367,0.09659
2021-08-15 11:55:00,0.09651,0.09684,0.09651,0.09669,516878,0.09669
2021-08-15 12:00:00,0.09670,0.09670,0.09638,0.09638,375451,0.09638
2021-08-15 12:05:00,0.09639,0.09657,0.09621,0.09623,456004,0.09623
2021-08-15 12:10:00,0.09631,0.09636,0.09556,0.09573,1344161,0.09573
2021-08-15 12:15:00,0.09571,0.09635,0.09564,0.09604,1085739,0.09604
2021-08-15 12:20:00,0.09620,0.09623,0.09583,0.09616,263289,0.09616
2021-08-15 12:25:00,0.09623,0.09635,0.09602,0.09635,372213,0.09635
2021-08-15 12:30:00,0.09635,0.09697,0.09630,0.09690,882856,0.09690
2021-08-15 12:35:00,0.09695,0.09709,0.09668,0.09678,1030638,0.09678
2021-08-15 12:40:00,0.09684,0.09684,0.09654,0.09660,898380,0.09660
2021-08-15 12:45:00,0.09662,0.09665,0.09624,0.09630,837715,0.09630
2021-08-15 12:50:00,0.09632,0.09652,0.09619,0.09647,640481,0.09647
2021-08-15 12:55:00,0.09645,0.09675,0.09644,0.09660,562040,0.09660
2021-08-15 13:00:00,0.09663,0.09663,0.09589,0.09611,1335005,0.09611
2021-08-15 13:05:00,0.09603,0.09675,0.09602,0.09673,936214,0.09673
2021-08-15 13:10:00,0.09673,0.09684,0.09646,0.09655,533439,0.09655
2021-08-15 13:15:00,0.09655,0.09655,0.09611,0.09614,300378,0.09614
2021-08-15 13:20:00,0.09610,0.09610,0.09582,0.09597,846500,0.09597
2021-08-15 13:25:00,0.09595,0.09609,0.09580,0.09604,462391,0.09604
2021-08-15 13:30:00,0.09602,0.09602,0.09569,0.09573,386237,0.09573
2021-08-15 13:35:00,0.09574,0.09584,0.09529,0.09536,985130,0.09536
2021-08-15 13:40:00,0.09539,0.09567,0.09521,0.09547,512357,0.09547
2021-08-15 13:45:00,0.09548,0.09559,0.09505,0.09518,800821,0.09518
2021-08-15 13:50:00,0.09513,0.09567,0.09509,0.09566,370242,0.09566
2021-08-15 13:55:00,0.09566,0.09568,0.09538,0.09551,259775,0.09551
2021-08-15 14:00:00,0.09550,0.09667,0.09531,0.09639,4695052,0.09639
2021-08-15 14:05:00,0.09642,0.09660,0.09633,0.09649,1159395,0.09649
2021-08-15 14:10:00,0.09654,0.09655,0.09618,0.09647,423402,0.09647
2021-08-15 14:15:00,0.09645,0.09705,0.09617,0.09678,3825841,0.09678
2021-08-15 14:20:00,0.09675,0.09693,0.09652,0.09684,673124,0.09684
2021-08-15 14:25:00,0.09681,0.09705,0.09657,0.09705,717827,0.09705
2021-08-15 14:30:00,0.09705,0.09708,0.09670,0.09703,1021557,0.09703
2021-08-15 14:35:00,0.09697,0.09702,0.09663,0.09669,1034057,0.09669
2021-08-15 14:40:00,0.09668,0.09676,0.09541,0.09571,3181710,0.09571
2021-08-15 14:45:00,0.09566,0.09705,0.09542,0.09688,3355165,0.09688
2021-08-15 14:50:00,0.09690,0.09850,0.09688,0.09799,5824589,0.09799
2021-08-15 14:55:00,0.09798,0.09810,0.09760,0.09807,1114093,0.09807
2021-08-15 15:00:00,0.09806,0.09806,0.09726,0.09800,2744572,0.09800
2021-08-15 15:05:00,0.09800,0.09910,0.09794,0.09852,3421884,0.09852
2021-08-15 15:10:00,0.09858,0.09858,0.09804,0.09821,1427867,0.09821
2021-08-15 15:15:00,0.09825,0.09843,0.09778,0.09783,705302,0.09783
2021-08-15 15:20:00,0.09789,0.09824,0.09760,0.09811,898435,0.09811
2021-08-15 15:25:00,0.09815,0.09822,0.09789,0.09791,482735,0.09791
2021-08-15 15:30:00,0.09796,0.09809,0.09779,0.09807,416140,0.09807
2021-08-15 15:35:00,0.09805,0.09805,0.09778,0.09794,310080,0.09794
2021-08-15 15:40:00,0.09789,0.09794,0.09735,0.09758,1295707,0.09758
2021-08-15 15:45:00,0.09759,0.09860,0.09728,0.09764,2992857,0.09764
2021-08-15 15:50:00,0.09762,0.09786,0.09713,0.09775,2046431,0.09775
2021-08-15 15:55:00,0.09773,0.09807,0.09769,0.09773,908042,0.09773
2021-08-15 16:00:00,0.09770,0.09805,0.09742,0.09743,1303649,0.09743
2021-08-15 16:05:00,0.09741,0.09765,0.09736,0.09755,493012,0.09755
2021-08-15 16:10:00,0.09755,0.09774,0.09744,0.09766,892380,0.09766
2021-08-15 16:15:00,0.09768,0.09768,0.09746,0.09753,433998,0.09753
2021-08-15 16:20:00,0.09750,0.09751,0.09674,0.09675,1375215,0.09675
2021-08-15 16:25:00,0.09675,0.09696,0.09660,0.09689,964676,0.09689
2021-08-15 16:30:00,0.09689,0.09689,0.09652,0.09669,719340,0.09669
2021-08-15 16:35:00,0.09666,0.09679,0.09658,0.09679,272555,0.09679
2021-08-15 16:40:00,0.09671,0.09693,0.09665,0.09684,129453,0.09684
2021-08-15 16:45:00,0.09681,0.09695,0.09671,0.09683,230532,0.09683
2021-08-15 16:50:00,0.09681,0.09720,0.09655,0.09695,839011,0.09695
2021-08-15 16:55:00,0.09692,0.09743,0.09691,0.09735,326566,0.09735
2021-08-15 17:00:00,0.09724,0.09765,0.09716,0.09755,1014406,0.09755
2021-08-15 17:05:00,0.09756,0.09757,0.09724,0.09747,701441,0.09747
2021-08-15 17:10:00,0.09745,0.09745,0.09713,0.09717,552162,0.09717
2021-08-15 17:15:00,0.09720,0.09721,0.09690,0.09708,494911,0.09708
2021-08-15 17:20:00,0.09707,0.09731,0.09701,0.09723,406186,0.09723
2021-08-15 17:25:00,0.09727,0.09752,0.09713,0.09730,479641,0.09730
2021-08-15 17:30:00,0.09727,0.09739,0.09703,0.09703,691376,0.09703
2021-08-15 17:35:00,0.09709,0.09709,0.09691,0.09703,450561,0.09703
2021-08-15 17:40:00,0.09707,0.09711,0.09681,0.09698,408768,0.09698
2021-08-15 17:45:00,0.09694,0.09724,0.09688,0.09703,270688,0.09703
2021-08-15 17:50:00,0.09707,0.09714,0.09683,0.09690,181695,0.09690
2021-08-15 17:55:00,0.09691,0.09701,0.09669,0.09678,481029,0.09678
2021-08-15 18:00:00,0.09676,0.09694,0.09637,0.09652,1702031,0.09652
2021-08-15 18:05:00,0.09652,0.09723,0.09641,0.09703,1308661,0.09703
2021-08-15 18:10:00,0.09700,0.09716,0.09676,0.09686,481690,0.09686
2021-08-15 18:15:00,0.09683,0.09706,0.09645,0.09677,847609,0.09677
2021-08-15 18:20:00,0.09672,0.09674,0.09648,0.09655,201331,0.09655
2021-08-15 18:25:00,0.09658,0.09727,0.09658,0.09718,486519,0.09718
2021-08-15 18:30:00,0.09712,0.09731,0.09696,0.09710,1080959,0.09710
2021-08-15 18:35:00,0.09718,0.09718,0.09680,0.09693,417610,0.09693
2021-08-15 18:40:00,0.09699,0.09709,0.09677,0.09704,205765,0.09704
2021-08-15 18:45:00,0.09703,0.09736,0.09696,0.09727,299985,0.09727
2021-08-15 18:50:00,0.09728,0.09745,0.09704,0.09730,605530,0.09730
2021-08-15 18:55:00,0.09738,0.09738,0.09715,0.09731,386545,0.09731
2021-08-15 19:00:00,0.09731,0.09762,0.09717,0.09762,557397,0.09762
2021-08-15 19:05:00,0.09762,0.09779,0.09740,0.09762,601306,0.09762
2021-08-15 19:10:00,0.09766,0.09795,0.09751,0.09795,215518,0.09795
2021-08-15 19:15:00,0.09795,0.09795,0.09761,0.09788,410396,0.09788
2021-08-15 19:20:00,0.09790,0.09792,0.09748,0.09768,448007,0.09768
2021-08-15 19:25:00,0.09767,0.09780,0.09762,0.09763,381934,0.09763
2021-08-15 19:30:00,0.09763,0.09763,0.09701,0.09733,1252571,0.09733
2021-08-15 19:35:00,0.09745,0.09762,0.09712,0.09746,462545,0.09746
2021-08-15 19:40:00,0.09753,0.09806,0.09746,0.09791,847587,0.09791
2021-08-15 19:45:00,0.09790,0.09796,0.09769,0.09786,359940,0.09786
2021-08-15 19:50:00,0.09790,0.09791,0.09769,0.09784,220705,0.09784
2021-08-15 19:55:00,0.09784,0.09806,0.09770,0.09798,305901,0.09798
2021-08-15 20:00:00,0.09793,0.09815,0.09779,0.09786,718354,0.09786
2021-08-15 20:05:00,0.09787,0.09790,0.09770,0.09779,224539,0.09779
2021-08-15 20:10:00,0.09778,0.09778,0.09744,0.09764,400808,0.09764
2021-08-15 20:15:00,0.09768,0.09776,0.09746,0.09763,180764,0.09763
2021-08-15 20:20:00,0.09763,0.09769,0.09730,0.09741,327170,0.09741
2021-08-15 20:25:00,0.09745,0.09766,0.09738,0.09747,328968,0.09747
2021-08-15 20:30:00,0.09750,0.09799,0.09750,0.09797,483365,0.09797
2021-08-15 20:35:00,0.09797,0.09802,0.09753,0.09787,466496,0.09787
2021-08-15 20:40:00,0.09785,0.09820,0.09783,0.09810,728733,0.09810
2021-08-15 20:45:00,0.09809,0.09862,0.09797,0.09860,1058141,0.09860
2021-08-15 20:50:00,0.09861,0.09869,0.09821,0.09852,1168443,0.09852
2021-08-15 20:55:00,0.09850,0.09896,0.09842,0.09896,571561,0.09896
2021-08-15 21:00:00,0.09895,0.09936,0.09874,0.09936,1684329,0.09936
2021-08-15 21:05:00,0.09936,0.09942,0.09880,0.09903,1055679,0.09903
2021-08-15 21:10:00,0.09904,0.09904,0.09873,0.09888,552692,0.09888
2021-08-15 21:15:00,0.09889,0.09969,0.09886,0.09965,1697964,0.09965
2021-08-15 21:20:00,0.09969,0.09974,0.09914,0.09947,1431400,0.09947
2021-08-15 21:25:00,0.09940,0.09987,0.09940,0.09973,1372999,0.09973
2021-08-15 21:30:00,0.09971,0.10024,0.09968,0.09996,2267263,0.09996
2021-08-15 21:35:00,0.10001,0.10063,0.09984,0.10050,1761268,0.10050
2021-08-15 21:40:00,0.10050,0.10126,0.10043,0.10117,2469420,0.10117
2021-08-15 21:45:00,0.10118,0.10130,0.10067,0.10103,1934420,0.10103
2021-08-15 21:50:00,0.10100,0.10119,0.10091,0.10097,1024251,0.10097
2021-08-15 21:55:00,0.10103,0.10260,0.10097,0.10202,6882531,0.10202
2021-08-15 22:00:00,0.10201,0.10329,0.10200,0.10256,4264399,0.10256
2021-08-15 22:05:00,0.10256,0.10609,0.10249,0.10513,10593630,0.10513
2021-08-15 22:10:00,0.10514,0.10654,0.10483,0.10563,11995237,0.10563
2021-08-15 22:15:00,0.10561,0.10570,0.10403,0.10505,7692354,0.10505
2021-08-15 22:20:00,0.10504,0.10522,0.10425,0.10466,3101808,0.10466
2021-08-15 22:25:00,0.10466,0.10467,0.10346,0.10357,4634070,0.10357
2021-08-15 22:30:00,0.10360,0.10373,0.10275,0.10349,4581891,0.10349
2021-08-15 22:35:00,0.10352,0.10446,0.10273,0.10367,4690129,0.10367
2021-08-15 22:40:00,0.10368,0.10559,0.10326,0.10539,7682674,0.10539
2021-08-15 22:45:00,0.10538,0.10580,0.10470,0.10493,5626312,0.10493
2021-08-15 22:50:00,0.10494,0.10774,0.10494,0.10698,10138352,0.10698
2021-08-15 22:55:00,0.10706,0.10850,0.10698,0.10786,8821167,0.10786
2021-08-15 23:00:00,0.10785,0.10868,0.10723,0.10787,7313120,0.10787
2021-08-15 23:05:00,0.10778,0.10785,0.10670,0.10692,3369346,0.10692
2021-08-15 23:10:00,0.10686,0.10759,0.10675,0.10679,1875751,0.10679
2021-08-15 23:15:00,0.10680,0.10724,0.10678,0.10723,1833018,0.10723
2021-08-15 23:20:00,0.10720,0.10746,0.10678,0.10710,2491003,0.10710
2021-08-15 23:25:00,0.10712,0.10768,0.10699,0.10730,1629989,0.10730
2021-08-15 23:30:00,0.10730,0.10736,0.10609,0.10614,2441915,0.10614
2021-08-15 23:35:00,0.10617,0.10712,0.10617,0.10679,2315005,0.10679
2021-08-15 23:40:00,0.10683,0.10683,0.10619,0.10661,2531106,0.10661
2021-08-15 23:45:00,0.10667,0.10720,0.10663,0.10680,1966298,0.10680
2021-08-15 23:50:00,0.10683,0.10695,0.10611,0.10629,1616144,0.10629
2021-08-15 23:55:00,0.10630,0.10836,0.10613,0.10834,2720109,0.10834
2021-08-16 00:00:00,0.10834,0.10841,0.10679,0.10718,4052530,0.10718
2021-08-16 00:05:00,0.10710,0.10728,0.10656,0.10700,1589434,0.10700
2021-08-16 00:10:00,0.10696,0.10849,0.10696,0.10841,1571219,0.10841
2021-08-16 00:15:00,0.10840,0.11009,0.10835,0.10953,8934203,0.10953
2021-08-16 00:20:00,0.10954,0.10954,0.10822,0.10824,4747749,0.10824
2021-08-16 00:25:00,0.10824,0.10850,0.10726,0.10739,2429017,0.10739
2021-08-16 00:30:00,0.10739,0.10754,0.10726,0.10726,1063838,0.10726
2021-08-16 00:35:00,0.10726,0.10888,0.10726,0.10747,4744576,0.10747
2021-08-16 00:40:00,0.10749,0.10765,0.10735,0.10760,717202,0.10760
2021-08-16 00:45:00,0.10762,0.10883,0.10760,0.10781,2193401,0.10781
2021-08-16 00:50:00,0.10786,0.10845,0.10782,0.10820,919417,0.10820
2021-08-16 00:55:00,0.10819,0.10832,0.10774,0.10809,1294347,0.10809
2021-08-16 01:00:00,0.10808,0.11025,0.10806,0.10963,5548691,0.10963
2021-08-16 01:05:00,0.10964,0.11300,0.10958,0.11282,16036488,0.11282
2021-08-16 01:10:00,0.11278,0.11300,0.10945,0.11214,16137300,0.11214
2021-08-16 01:15:00,0.11212,0.11243,0.10953,0.11020,8878423,0.11020
2021-08-16 01:20:00,0.11019,0.11035,0.10880,0.10977,4978442,0.10977
2021-08-16 01:25:00,0.10975,0.11099,0.10948,0.11059,3514627,0.11059
2021-08-16 01:30:00,0.11054,0.11194,0.11050,0.11187,5328608,0.11187
2021-08-16 01:35:00,0.11181,0.11186,0.11000,0.11030,4483301,0.11030
2021-08-16 01:40:00,0.11029,0.11110,0.10986,0.11098,4019540,0.11098
2021-08-16 01:45:00,0.11103,0.11111,0.11026,0.11063,2491489,0.11063
2021-08-16 01:50:00,0.11064,0.11089,0.10971,0.11029,2936959,0.11029
2021-08-16 01:55:00,0.11031,0.11087,0.11009,0.11082,1109563,0.11082
2021-08-16 02:00:00,0.11078,0.11131,0.10913,0.10946,5027246,0.10946
2021-08-16 02:05:00,0.10946,0.10999,0.10928,0.10959,2753645,0.10959
2021-08-16 02:10:00,0.10962,0.11000,0.10959,0.10994,1133122,0.10994
2021-08-16 02:15:00,0.10990,0.11150,0.10990,0.11104,3142623,0.11104
2021-08-16 02:20:00,0.11101,0.11249,0.11092,0.11214,6178772,0.11214
2021-08-16 02:25:00,0.11213,0.11266,0.11200,0.11211,3361049,0.11211
2021-08-16 02:30:00,0.11214,0.11235,0.11100,0.11183,6650246,0.11183
2021-08-16 02:35:00,0.11185,0.11246,0.11101,0.11112,2216568,0.11112
2021-08-16 02:40:00,0.11111,0.11166,0.11095,0.11102,1418282,0.11102
2021-08-16 02:45:00,0.11104,0.11210,0.11104,0.11167,1975305,0.11167
2021-08-16 02:50:00,0.11170,0.11354,0.11170,0.11341,4745238,0.11341
2021-08-16 02:55:00,0.11352,0.11445,0.11328,0.11381,7154140,0.11381
2021-08-16 03:00:00,0.11379,0.11399,0.11247,0.11256,4473517,0.11256
2021-08-16 03:05:00,0.11260,0.11274,0.11188,0.11205,2365967,0.11205
2021-08-16 03:10:00,0.11205,0.11240,0.11160,0.11212,2181630,0.11212
2021-08-16 03:15:00,0.11212,0.11331,0.11196,0.11199,2671132,0.11199
2021-08-16 03:20:00,0.11203,0.11288,0.11196,0.11248,2479541,0.11248
2021-08-16 03:25:00,0.11250,0.11466,0.11250,0.11380,7486247,0.11380
2021-08-16 03:30:00,0.11387,0.11473,0.11372,0.11391,6428209,0.11391
2021-08-16 03:35:00,0.11400,0.11455,0.11390,0.11427,3195689,0.11427
2021-08-16 03:40:00,0.11425,0.11436,0.11310,0.11354,4194721,0.11354
2021-08-16 03:45:00,0.11353,0.11386,0.11306,0.11314,4911829,0.11314
2021-08-16 03:50:00,0.11317,0.11322,0.11248,0.11294,2171526,0.11294
2021-08-16 03:55:00,0.11289,0.11352,0.11285,0.11320,2310164,0.11320
2021-08-16 04:00:00,0.11321,0.11339,0.11228,0.11294,2490559,0.11294
2021-08-16 04:05:00,0.11294,0.11311,0.11268,0.11280,1328500,0.11280
2021-08-16 04:10:00,0.11280,0.11374,0.11275,0.11341,3127305,0.11341
2021-08-16 04:15:00,0.11341,0.11567,0.11334,0.11531,6390195,0.11531
2021-08-16 04:20:00,0.11529,0.11828,0.11503,0.11818,13150161,0.11818
2021-08-16 04:25:00,0.11817,0.11887,0.11678,0.11723,16415597,0.11723
2021-08-16 04:30:00,0.11716,0.11779,0.11565,0.11592,9934460,0.11592
2021-08-16 04:35:00,0.11586,0.11632,0.11357,0.11364,11374238,0.11364
2021-08-16 04:40:00,0.11364,0.11470,0.11350,0.11355,6486211,0.11355
2021-08-16 04:45:00,0.11359,0.11483,0.11231,0.11309,11397993,0.11309
2021-08-16 04:50:00,0.11310,0.11359,0.11141,0.11141,11940502,0.11141
2021-08-16 04:55:00,0.11141,0.11283,0.11117,0.11248,7553309,0.11248
2021-08-16 05:00:00,0.11251,0.11312,0.11249,0.11306,4484691,0.11306
2021-08-16 05:05:00,0.11306,0.11331,0.11304,0.11328,1879152,0.11328
2021-08-16 05:10:00,0.11326,0.11384,0.11310,0.11374,3460818,0.11374
2021-08-16 05:15:00,0.11375,0.11566,0.11375,0.11460,6249251,0.11460
2021-08-16 05:20:00,0.11461,0.11621,0.11383,0.11567,6087717,0.11567
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It is still not reproducible. But trying to help nonetheless, what are the outputs of: `type(df)` and, assuming `pandas.DataFrame`, then `df.dtypes` and `df.info()`?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> for type(df) and df.dtypes is float64, and then for the whole df.info() Index: 400 entries, 2021-08-19 08:15:00 to 2021-08-20 17:30:00
Data columns (total 10 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------      --------------  -----  
 3   Close       400 non-null    float64

Comment: Oh, I guess the range of the values is too small for `prominence=2`. Try just `find_peaks(s)`. Then adapt the parameters `distance` and `prominence` for something appropriate given your data. Read carefully what these parameters mean, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [`scipy.signal.find_peaks`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html).

**Important:** note that all of the following techniques have **peak-ahead bias** (they use points in the future when considering any given point), with severe implications for any sort of trading algorithm.

With that disclaimer out of the way, here is an example to find local maximas (for local minimas, you'd just use `find_peaks(-s, ...)`):

```py
# random walk
np.random.seed(0)
s = np.random.normal(size=200).cumsum()

# find local maximas
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

imax, propmax = find_peaks(s)
plt.plot(s)
plt.scatter(x=imax, y=s[imax])
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can change which peaks are retained by specifying conditions for a peak's properties. For a complete example, including finding minimas as well:

```py
kwargs = dict(distance=5, prominence=2)
imax, propmax = find_peaks(s, **kwargs)
imin, propmin = find_peaks(-s, **kwargs)

plt.plot(s)
plt.scatter(x=imax, y=s[imax], c='b')
plt.scatter(x=imin, y=s[imin], c='r')
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can combine this with pre-filtering of your series. A common technique to filter out noise is the [median filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter).

```py
z = pd.Series(s).rolling(4, center=True).median()
z.plot()

kwargs = dict(distance=5, prominence=2)
imax, propmax = find_peaks(z, **kwargs)
imin, propmin = find_peaks(-z, **kwargs)

plt.scatter(x=imax, y=z[imax], c='b')
plt.scatter(x=imin, y=z[imin], c='r')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Finally, to efficiently investigate "peak-to-trough" intervals and other similar properties of a time-series, techniques from [Detrended Fluctuation Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detrended_fluctuation_analysis) are very powerful. This is beyond the scope of this answer, though.

Comment: Can this also be done for the reverse, the minimas as well?

Comment: yes, I modified my answer to include: "for local minimas, you'd just use `find_peaks(-s, ...)`".

Comment: is there a specific sort of data input required, doesn't seem to work with pd series converted to np arrays?

Comment: What error do you see? Since you didn't provide a MRE, I made one: a simple `np.array` of a random walk. Your data is probably different, but in principle, any `np.array` of type float should work with this. If you use directly a Pandas Series, e.g. `df['column']`, then it comes with whatever index the DataFrame has, and subsetting by `[imax]` (integer index) won't work as is. Either use `series.values[imax]` or `series.iloc[imax]`.

Comment: The issue is that it just doesn't work out any imax or imin, I'm using a np.array with floats. Here's the code you might see something I'm not.

ticker_df = download_binance_candles(symbol, "5m")
    s = np.array(ticker_df["Close"].to_list(), dtype=np.float64)
    print(s)

    kwargs = dict(distance=5, prominence=2)
    imax, propmax = find_peaks(s, **kwargs)
    imin, propmin = find_peaks(-s, **kwargs)

    plt.plot(s)
    plt.scatter(x=imax, y=s[imax], c='b')
    plt.scatter(x=imin, y=s[imin], c='r')
    print(imax, imin)
    plt.show()

Comment: please update your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It doesn't have to be exactly your data from wherever you are downloading it, but it should be consistent with types, shape, etc. so that a solution to it would also mean a solution to your problem.